# My react-reducer state is not being updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

My reducer is not updating the state.My actions are being dispatched but my reducer is not updating my state.My application state has two object product(Array) and cart(array).

My application has two reducers

1. cartReducer

```js
export  function cartReducer(state={cart:[
{id:1},
{id:2}
]},actions){
        switch(actions.payload)
        {
            case "ADD_TO_CART":
            console.log("Reducer called")
            return {cart:[...state.cart,...actions.payload]}
            default:
            return state;
        }
    }
```

2. productReducer

```js
export  function ProductReducer(state={
product:[{
    id:1,
    ProductName:"LG TV",
    Description:"This is the best tv available today in the market.This is the best tv available today in the market.This is the best tv available today in the market.This is the best tv available today in the market",
    Price:200,

    },
    {
        id:2,
        ProductName:"Apple TV",
        Description:"This is the best tv available today in the market",
  
        Price:300,
    },
    {
        id:3,
        ProductName:"Hp TV",
        Description:"This is the best tv available today in the market",
  
        Price:400,
    },{
        id:5,
        ProductName:"LC TV",
        Description:"This is the best tv available today in the market",
        Price:700,
    }]},actions){
    switch(actions.payload)
    {
        case "ADD_PRODUCT":
        return {product:[...state.product,...actions.payload]}
        default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

3. My combineReducer (index.js)

```js
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {ProductReducer} from './ProductReducer.js';
import {cartReducer} from './cartReducer.js';

const rootReducer=combineReducers({
    product:ProductReducer,
    cart:cartReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

My actions files are:

1. cartActions

```js
export function addToCart(data) 
 {
     console.log("Actions called")
     return {
         type:"ADD_TO_CART",
          payload: data
     } 
 };
```

My main index.js file

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import '../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
import '../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js';
import reducers from './reducers/index';
const store=createStore(reducers);

ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
<App />
</Provider>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I am able to access  initial state from the reducers using mapStateToProps in my components ProductDescription.js and ProductList.js

1. ProductList.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import ProductDescription from './ProductDescription';
class ProductList extends Component {
     componentDidMount(){
     }
  render() {
      const arr=this.props.product.map((data)=>{
        return(
        <li key={data.id}>
       <ProductDescription data={data} />

          </li>
      )});
 
    return (
      <div className="row">
      <div className="col s12 ">
        <div className="card ">
          <div className="card-content ">
          <h2 >Product List</h2>
          <br/>
          <hr/>
          <br/>
          <ul>
           {arr}
            </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
        </div>      
    );
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state)
{
  return {
    cart:state.cart.cart,
    product:state.product.product,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProductList);
```

2. ProductDescription.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import  {addToCart} from '../Actions/cartActions';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

class ProductDescription extends Component {
handleCart()
  {
    const data1=[...this.props.cart,
      {
        id:this.props.data.id,
        ProductName:this.props.data.ProductName,
        Description:this.props.data.Description,
        Price:this.props.data.Price,
      }];
      console.log(data1);
   this.props.addToCart(data1);
  setTimeout(()=>{console.log(this.props.cart)},3000);
  
  } 
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col s12">
        <div className="card">
        <div className="card-content">
          <div className="card-title">
          {this.props.data.ProductName}
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <div>
          {this.props.data.Description}
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <div >
          Price :{this.props.data.Price}
          <br/>
          </div>
          
          <div className="right">
            <button  onClick={this.handleCart.bind(this)} className="waves-effect waves-light btn" >Add To Cart</button>      
            </div>
            <br/>
            <br/>
        </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
    );
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state)
{
  return{
  cart:state.cart.cart,
  }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    addToCart:addToCart  
  },dispatch)
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(ProductDescription);
```

But I am unable to get an updated cart state from the console.log(this.props.cart) in ProductDescription.js. Even though I have a timeout for 3000.I have even put a console.log statement in CartReducer.js to check whether the reducer is being accessed or not.But the console.log statement is not being called.

Below is my console output :

[Console.log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwcoZ.jpg)

Comment: have you tried narrowing things down? creating the smallest possible scenario with less files & code that hopefully reproduces the issue?

Comment: I solved it .I had made a very stupid blunder.In my cartReducer.js instead of using the type of actions as the choice in switch case I was using payload of actions. I had written switch(action.payload) but it should be switch(action.type).

Comment: awesome. so maybe it's best to delete this question now.. so others won't bother with it :)